# How to configure NSubstitute NOT call internal virtual method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I want unit test this class

```
public class Email 
{ 
    public async virtual Task<bool> Send(  )
    {
        //code
        await Save();
    }

    internal virtual async   Task<bool> Save( )
    {

    } 
}
```

and this unit test code

```
var email = Substitute.ForPartsOf<Email>( ); 
email.When(x => x.Save( )).DoNotCallBase(); --> why x.Save will call the real implementation code
email.Save( ).ReturnsForAnyArgs(true);
```

and is this a correct way to unit test internal method? As i tried changed modifier from **internal** to **public** and the unit test is fine.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make the `internal` member visible to `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2`. This assembly is created by the Castle DynamicProxy library used by NSubstitute (and many other .NET mocking libraries) to create the substitute/mock types.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

If you install the [NSubstitute.Analyzers package](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) it should [prompt you](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute.Analyzers/blob/dev/documentation/rules/NS2003.md) about this case.

Comment: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/ says to use this attribute in the test assembly, when what they mean is really to use it in the assembly under test, as you've shown here

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've raised an issue here: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/630

Comment: It started to work, when I added this line into the Test project's AssemblyInfo.cs